# Duda con constructor al crear un JFrame. Java

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, herencia, constructor

Tengo una duda a la hora de poder utilizar los métodos desde una clase que hereda de JFrame, como esta:

```
class MarcoLibre extends JFrame{

}
```

En el constructor, sí que puedo acceder a los métodos que heredan de JFrame (y sus correspondientes herencias).

```
class MarcoLibre extends JFrame{

   public MarcoLibre(){
      setTitle("JAVA");  //funciona
   }
 }
```

Sin embargo,si lo hago fuera del constructor, no funciona. ¿Por qué desde el constructor sí que puedo y desde fuera de él no?¿Cómo podría hacerse sin estar en el constructor?

```
class MarcoLibre extends JFrame{

 setTitle("JAVA");  //no funciona

}
```

Luego tengo mi clase main donde me creo un marco.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class LibreDisposicion {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MarcoLibre miMarco = new MarcoLibre();
    miMarco.setVisible(true);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que todas las sentencias deben ir dentro de un metodo de la clase y no en la clase misma.

```
class MarcoLibre extends JFrame{
    public void titulo(){
        setTitle("JAVA");
    }
}
```

Puedes acceder a cualquiera de los métodos de la clase JFrame(Clase Padre) en cualquiera de los métodos de la clase MarcoLibre(Clase Hija), no solamente desde el constructor.

```
public class LibreDisposicion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MarcoLibre miMarco = new MarcoLibre();
        miMarco.titulo();
        miMarco.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto ocurre porque `setVisible` es un método que pertenece a la Clase `JFrame`, para poder utilizar cualquier funcion o propiedad de una clase heredada se requiere de un **objeto** es cual lo invoque, en este caso el Constructor se encarga de crear ese objeto que requerimos, también podemos apuntar a dicho objeto con la palabra reservada `this` que hace referencia a la propiedades y métodos de la clase.

**¿cuando se crea este objeto?**

Al instanciar la clase lo primero que se ejecuta es el constructor el cual crea el objeto mencionado.

es tu caso la instancia de clase sería `MarcoLibre miMarco = new MarcoLibre();`

*la Sintaxis es la siguiente:*

> [tipo de dato] [nombre instancia] = new [constructor]